# Transpose 2 columns into 8 columns (consolidating the data from column 1)

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet of tons of data; about 370,000 rows in my first export. However, it looks like "A" in the screenshot link below. I need a quick way to format this data to look like "B" in the screenshot link below. Does anyone have a trick to do this?

[excel_example_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFzaW.png)

I've been able to do it manually, but with so much data (and the fact that I will be exporting many more of this same type of data), it's going to take way too much time. The steps I take to do this manually are:

1. Filter the data to show only 0 from column A
2. Copy the entire column B range
3. Paste into a new sheet under the first column
4. Repeat steps 1-3 for numbers 1-7 from column A

This is how I made the screenshot.

EDIT: Someone marked this as duplicate. Please re-read the way the other ticket is displaying the data. It is in no way the same as what I need other than splitting into multiple columns. I need the data to remain linked to the "0-7" numbers I have on the left side. It can't simply be split for printing purposes. The end result will eventually be a chart.

Here's what my data looks like with the answer from the linked ticket:

[failed_transpose_example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqm5I.png)

EDIT2: I guess it's not completely obvious from my explanation, but I know little to nothing about Excel functions/statements.

EDIT3: @ScottCraner's answer in the comments did what I needed. Different than the answer in the linked ticket.

Comment: Is it always Eight, and will it always repeat fully?  or will some be missing?

Comment: @ScottCraner It will always repeat fully, and there will always be 8 columns

Comment: re: [edit] ; The method is exactly the same although you may have to change the IsOdd stagger to something involving Mod.

Comment: @Jeeped Can you explain how the method is the same? Does the function that you gave in the linked ticket also consolidate the data from column 1 into 8 specific columns of their own?

EDIT: I'm also not sure what you mean by "something involving Mod"

Comment: Put this in D2 : `=INDEX(B:B,(Row(1:1)-1)*8+COLUMN(A:A))` and copy over 8 columns and down as far as you need.  Then use copy/Paste special for the headers.

Comment: @ScottCraner Not quite. Maybe I copied the formula wrong? I would paste a screenshot, but StackOverflow won't let me post more than 2 links. I ended up with a grid of zeros, and only the 1st column kind of looks like it may be the data, but I don't fully trust that it's all actually the "0" data.

Comment: `=INDEX($B:$B,(Row(1:1)-1)*8+COLUMN(A:A))`

Comment: @ScottCraner That second one seems to do the trick (looks like you just added $ to the Bs). Just quickly compared 40 lines of the data I ended up with to my original data, and it all matches up.

If it's not too much trouble, would you be able to briefly explain what is being done in what you suggested?

Comment: Feel free to google what each function does.  You can also use `Evaluate Formula` on the Formula tab, it will walk you through the steps as it resolves.

Comment: @ScottCraner If you add your comment as an Answer, I will mark it as such. Thanks!